# I can't change event status when page opening in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to FLutter. I am using Bloc pattern as a design pattern.
When clicked a button or text changed I successfully changed the event of the bloc.

But I need to get data when the page opens and bind it to a list.
I don't know how can I change the bloc event to do that?

I've tried to add BlocBuilder in InitState but it didn't work.

here is my code.

```
class OrderListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderListWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrderListWidgetState createState() => _OrderListWidgetState();
}

class _OrderListWidgetState extends State<OrderListWidget> {
  late List<WorkOrder> workOrderList;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => WorkOrderBloc(
          workOrderRepo: (context).read<WorkOrderRepository>(),
          type: WorkOrderType.mt),
      child: BlocListener<WorkOrderBloc, WorkOrderState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          final formStatus = state.formStatus;

          if (formStatus is FormSubmitting) {
            LoadingDialog.openLoadingDialog(context, 'Please Wait');
          } else {
            if (formStatus is! InitialFormStatus) {
              LoadingDialog.closeLoadingDialog(context);
            }
            if (formStatus is SubmissionFailed) {
              SnackbarWidget.show(
                  context, formStatus.exception.toString(), Colors.red);
            }
            if (formStatus is SubmissionSuccess) {
              setState(() {
                workOrderList = state.workOrderList!;
              });
            }
          }
        },
        child: BlocBuilder<WorkOrderBloc, WorkOrderState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return _myListView(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    context
        .read<WorkOrderBloc>()
        .add(WorkOrderListing(orderType: WorkOrderType.mt));
    super.initState();
  }
}

Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {
  var selected = false;
  
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: workOrderList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          value: selected,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState() {
              selected = value!;
            }
          },
          title: Text(workOrderList[index].Name),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way:

```
return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => WorkOrderBloc(workOrderRepo: WorkOrderRepository())
        ..add(PickingOrderListing()),
      child: BlocListener<WorkOrderBloc, WorkOrderState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
              ....
        }
)
```

using
..add(YOUR EVENT)
after the BlocProvider worked.